# Formatando o texto em caixa alta - maiúsculas

Tags: css, html5

Estou construindo uma aplicação utilizando PHP e sou iniciante em desenvolvimento de sistemas. Como faço para formatar os campos tipo texto para ficaram com as letras todas maiúsculas?

Answer (score 5):

Isso faz-se com CSS:

```
div {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/rhzykegg/

Se quiseres mesmo fazer em PHP podes usar o [strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) para `ISO-8859-1` e [mb_strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php) pra `UTF8`

```
echo strtoupper('Texto'); // dá TEXTO
```

Answer (score 1):

Carlos, a formatação de textos é própria de linguagem FRONT-END, como html, css, javascript e outras, no PHP a função de string strtoupper($text) pode lhe valer, porém a forma mais correta cabe ao CSS com o argumento 'font-variant' trazendo algo como 'small-caps', você pode ter uma classe que lhe retorne todo o texto em versalete por exemplo.

Você pode ter o mesmo efeito  em javascript:

```
getElementByTagName("INPUT").style.fontVariant="small-caps";
```

<input type="text" value="texto padrão" class="versalete" />

em css:

```
.versalete{font-variant:small-caps;}
```

Comment: legal a informação extra de código, mas tipograficamente, maíúsculas e small-caps são coisas completamente diferentes. Uppercase faz com que as letras todas sejam exibidas em maiúsculas (forma e tamanho). Small-caps faz com que as letras minúsculas sejam mostradas com forma maiúscula e tamanho da minúscula (x-height).

Answer (score -2):

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="nomeFantasia" id="nomeFantasia" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" >
```

Use oninput retornando a entrada em caixa alta

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).